# Resize StringItem Button in J2ME

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

Please let me know how to resize `StringItem` button. I want to make it large.

```
btnExit= new StringItem("", "Exit", StringItem.BUTTON);
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Resizing,Setting padding and Margin through Pure J2ME is very difficult. Even though you managed to do it somehow, it wont fit with all device screens. So, I suggest you to use [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/)(Light Weight User Interface Toolkit). Customizing all the components in LWUIT is very easy and you can attain very good UI using it with very less memory footprint.

Comment: if you feel the answer is helpful , accept it as an answer to your question. So, that it will be helpful for the future referrers.